# Set image in imageview for certain time

Tags: android, imageview

I have an imageview that has image 1 , and a button.
I need the button when pressed to change the image source to image2 for 1sec only then have image1 set .
I am a beginner in java and android,Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Handler` for this:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageViewId);
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)); // set image1

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2)); // set image2
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)); // switch back to image1
    }, 1000L);    // 1 second delay | change this value to shorten/lengthen delay
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // set thr image to image1
    }
};

 private void onButtonClickHandler() {
    // set the image to image2

    //remove
    handler.removeCallbacks(runable);
    // post a delay
    handler.postDelayed(runable, 1000);
 }
```

**OR:**

```
private void onButtonClickHandler() {
    // set the image to image2

    //cancel
    timer.cancel();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, 1000);
}


private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Comment: This code have a flaw, when you would click a button with a 0.5 second interval you would expect to refresh the timer, but it would show your old Image after 0.5 second more instead of 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setImage(img2);
Thread.sleep(1000);
imageView.setImage(img1);
```